# How to initialise view again after changin the html

Tags: jquery, fancybox, backbone.js

I have a view in backbone.js

```
App.Backbone.UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        className: 'pp-entry group',
        template :_.template('<img src="i/pp-pic-8.png" class="pp-pic" alt="" /><a class="pp-pic-wrap show-fb" href="#pp-details-<%=username%>"></a>),
        templatedetails:_.template('`<div style="display:none"><div id="pp-details-<%=username%>" class="pp-details"><div class="cta clear"><input type="button" name="" value="Add to my Wallet" class="mar-right-10 addtowallet" /><input type="button" class="mar-right-10 addtogib" name="" value="Add to gib as link" /><input type="button" name="" value="Close" onclick="$.fancybox.close()" /></div></div><.div>'`)

        //Here is the click event defined

        events:{    
            "click .addtowallet":"addlinktowallet",
            "click .addtogib":"addasgiblink"
            },

       //Render contents

       render: function() { 
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        $(this.el).attr('id', 'pp-'+this.model.get('username')); //This is used to set the id for the "li" tag

        $(this.el).append(this.templatedetails(this.model.toJSON())); //appending to the template
     $(".show-fb").fancybox();
        },

        //But when i am defining the function the click event does not get triggered

        addasgiblink: function(){
            alert("gib button clicked");        
            },

        addlinktowallet: function(){
            alert("wallet button clicked");     
            }
});
```

this is the html generating .
what is happening here as i analyise is fancy box is adding his html in my div so clickevnet on addlinktowallet and other are not working .
Please suggest what can i do to make it work with fancybox ?

```
<li id="pp-rahul" class="pp-entry group">
<img class="pp-pic" alt="" src="i/pp-pic-8.png">
<a class="pp-pic-wrap show-fb" href="#pp-details-rahul"></a>

<div style="display: none;">
 // added by fancybox 
<div style="width: auto; height: auto; overflow: auto; position: relative;">
<div id="pp-details-rahul" class="pp-details">
<img class="pp-pic" alt="" src="i/pp-pic-2.png">
<h4 class="pp-name">rahul</h4>
<p class="pp-attr">
</p>
<p class="pp-attr mar-btm-20">
       //here other html are coming .
</p>
<div class="cta clear">
   //here the html of button 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `live()` in your view code to register click event-

Docs- [**live**](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: right thanks already used the live event , any ways thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

How to initialise view again after changin the html: Call the render function again.

The BackBone Events that are defined are registered as event delegates upon rendering the view and remove the requirement of having to call JQuery's Live event on a particular element.

The BackBone documentation is very extensive: [delegateEvents](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents)

> delegateEvents: Uses jQuery's delegate function to provide declarative callbacks for DOM events within a view.
>
> ...
>
> Using delegateEvents provides a number of advantages over manually using jQuery to bind events to child elements during render. All attached callbacks are bound to the view before being handed off to jQuery, so when the callbacks are invoked, this continues to refer to the view object. When delegateEvents is run again, perhaps with a different events hash, all callbacks are removed and delegated afresh — useful for views which need to behave differently when in different modes.

Comment: I am using fancybox ,  Can  I do it without `live` ,  if yes then Please update your answer with code .